# is there possibility to define custom access log in nested?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, terraform

can anyone help me to setup custom access log for apigateway?

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_method_settings" "api" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id}"
  stage_name  = "${var.stage_name}"
  method_path = "*/*"

  settings {
    throttling_burst_limit = 1000
    throttling_rate_limit  = 5000

    #   log_full_requests      = true
    data_trace_enabled = true
    metrics_enabled    = true
    logging_level      = "INFO"
  }
}
```

is there possibility to define custom access log in nested inside  ?

```
destination_arn = "${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.lg.arn}"
format = ""
}
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to override the access log group for a single method on a stage? That's not possible in AWS at all currently and access log groups are always configured at the stage level afaik. Is there a reason you'd want to separate the log groups for a method?

Comment: now sorted out issue I understand. its sending log in side log group made by own name like API-Gateway-Execution-Logs_{satage_name}. Can I rename this cloudwatch group as per my own naming convention.